Document Search Results when Document metadata is not stored in the Document entity table
I have a situation with PolicyCenter that could apply to any InsuranceSuite app. The IDocumentMetadataSource plugin uses an implementation that calls an external DMS to search for documents. The Document table in the database is empty, all document metadata is stored in the DMS and retrieved via a web service call. For accounts that have a large number of documents, sometimes the searching of documents causes a huge performance issue. I have tracked the performance issue to this likely culprit:
Original RowIterator in DocumentsLV.pcf:
<RowIterator
  appendPageInfo="true"
  editable="false"
  elementName="Document"
  hasCheckBoxes="true"
  value="docQuery"
  valueType="gw.api.database.IQueryBeanResult<entity.Document>">

RowIterator in the custom LV:
<RowIterator
  appendPageInfo="true"
  editable="false"
  elementName="Document"
  hasCheckBoxes="true"
  value="docQuery.toList()"
  valueType="List<entity.Document>">

In the custom LV, all the documents are put into a list in application memory, which is where the application hangs when searching for documents on an Account with many documents. Here is my question though:
Since all the document metadata is pulled from a webservice call, does the resultant list of documents somehow get stored in the nonPersistantEntity DocumentSearchResult? This would in theory allow the full results to be "parked" in the DB and pulled 15 (or whatever the page size is) at a time into the application memory when using the IQueryBeanResult syntax instead of calling toList(). Thanks

NonPersistentEntity usage is exactly what it says - there is no persistence in the database.  While you can wrap the metadata results in a non-persistent entity that won't really change your bottleneck - it just wraps an entity around the data elements you already have.
I can imagine a few ways to approach your issue.  One way would be to turn this into a SearchPanel and send your filtering criteria to the external DMS and let it do the work of filtering.  This offloads the document data from the PC runtime and simplifies the PC-side logic.  This approach assumes the DMS API supports the necessary filtering and is performant.
Another alternative is to "index" the incoming data by building appropriate Maps that reflect the filter criteria.  That would let you subset the results quickly at least some small number of dimensions at the cost of "pre-processing" the result set to build the maps.  This also increases the memory footprint in the appserver so some testing will be needed to confirm this, or some careful design to minimize duplication of data.
Finally, take a careful look at how the DMS API results are being held.  By default (afaik) the result set from a webservice call is XML wrapped with gosu elements.  If that's the case then iterating over that large XML content is likely to be slow.  Maybe you need to pre-process the result set into POGO objects in a list/map to make them perform appropriately.  This is a subset of the change I mentioned above.  In fact, you could use non-persistent entities instead of the POGO but I don't know if that would actually gain you anything.
Good luck!

Thanks Marty. I will try a few of these and see how they go.
